# Java looping is not exiting when typing "quit"

Tags: java, loops

Hello I can't seem to get my while loop to terminate the code when I'm typing the String "quit". Any help would be appreciated.

```
package CalculatorProg;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        BinaryExpression operation = new BinaryExpression();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in); 


        while(true){


            String calc;
            String num1;
            String num2;

            num1 = userinput.next();
            calc = userinput.next();
            num2 = userinput.next();

            String[] input = new String[5];
            input[0] = num1;
            input[1] = " ";
            input[2] = calc;
            input[3] = " ";
            input[4] = num2;


            if(calc.equals("+")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(calc);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(" ");
                int x, y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2);

                System.out.println(operation.Add(x, y));
            }    
            else if(calc.equals("-")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(calc);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(" ");
                int x, y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                System.out.println(operation.Subtract(x, y));
            }   
            else if(calc.equals("*")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(calc);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(" ");
                int x, y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                System.out.println(operation.Multiply(x, y));
            }   
            else if(calc.equals("/")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(calc);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(" ");
                int x, y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                System.out.println(operation.Divide(x, y));
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The operation is not valid.");
                }
            if(input[0].equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                   break;
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you must be getting 'The operation is not valid'. Put your if condition for quit under else if. If you use if after an if it tests for the first and then comes to the second if.

Comment: What's the purpose of this `input` array? Just to make things more complicated?

Comment: After `num1 = userinput.next(); `use `if(num1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                   break;
            }`

Comment: Why don't you try to give a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

The code is waiting on user input at  calc = userinput.next();

public boolean hasNext()
Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Comment: There's not much point in calling `Scanner::hasNext` when the input source is `System.in`; That method is more useful when using a `Scanner` to parse files or strings

Answer (score 0):

You should first validate the input inside its own condition.

Example:

```
package CalculatorProg;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BinaryExpression operation = new BinaryExpression();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);


        while (true) {


            String calc;
            String num1;
            String num2;

            num1 = userinput.next();
            calc = userinput.next();
            num2 = userinput.next();

            String[] input = new String[5];
            input[0] = num1;
            input[1] = " ";
            input[2] = calc;
            input[3] = " ";
            input[4] = num2;

            if (!input[0].equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                if (calc.equals("+")) {
                    System.out.print(num1);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(calc);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(num2);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print("=");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    int x, y;
                    x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                    y = Integer.parseInt(num2);

                    System.out.println(operation.Add(x, y));
                } else if (calc.equals("-")) {
                    System.out.print(num1);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(calc);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(num2);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print("=");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    int x, y;
                    x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                    y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                    System.out.println(operation.Subtract(x, y));
                } else if (calc.equals("*")) {
                    System.out.print(num1);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(calc);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(num2);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print("=");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    int x, y;
                    x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                    y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                    System.out.println(operation.Multiply(x, y));
                } else if (calc.equals("/")) {
                    System.out.print(num1);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(calc);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print(num2);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print("=");
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    int x, y;
                    x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                    y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                    System.out.println(operation.Divide(x, y));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The operation is not valid.");
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for the 'quit' before any of the other conditions:

```
package CalculatorProg;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        BinaryExpression operation = new BinaryExpression();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in); 


        while(true){


            String calc;
            String num1;
            String num2;

            num1 = userinput.next();
            if(num1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                   break;
            }
            calc = userinput.next();
            num2 = userinput.next();

            String[] input = new String[5];
            input[0] = num1;
            input[1] = " ";
            input[2] = calc;
            input[3] = " ";
            input[4] = num2;



            if(calc.equals("+")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(calc);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(" ");
                int x, y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2);

                System.out.println(operation.Add(x, y));
            }    
            else if(calc.equals("-")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(calc);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(" ");
                int x, y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                System.out.println(operation.Subtract(x, y));
            }   
            else if(calc.equals("*")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(calc);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(" ");
                int x, y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                System.out.println(operation.Multiply(x, y));
            }   
            else if(calc.equals("/")){
                System.out.print(num1);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(calc);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(num2);
                System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print("=");
                System.out.print(" ");
                int x, y;
                x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                System.out.println(operation.Divide(x, y));
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The operation is not valid.");
                }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The problem may have been that it is trying to parse 'quit' to an integer, which would cause an error and never reach the quit condition.

Or it could be that the code is waiting for an input at 'calc = userinput.next();', but i'm not sure if you tried entering the next two inputs

Answer (score 0):

Code is probably stuck on the second `next()` call. Try just using a single call to `nextLine()` and a call to `String::split`

```
String input = userinput.nextLine(); // Get an entire line

if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){ // Check the exit first
    break;
}
// If it hasn't exited assume that its an equation

String[] inputSplit = input.split(); // Split the input by spaces
String calc inputSplit[1];
String num1 inputSplit[0];
String num2 inputSplit[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will fit for you. I give it to some helping information to users when the program is running. You can try it out! :D

```
package CalculatorProg;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainDriver {

public static void main(String[] args){

    BinaryExpression operation = new BinaryExpression();

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in); 


    while(true){


        String calc;
        String num1;
        String num2;

        System.out.print("Number 1 (if quit then program exits) =");
        num1 = userinput.next();
        if(num1.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            System.out.println("program quit");
            break;
        }
        System.out.print("Operator =");
        calc = userinput.next();
        System.out.print("Number 2 =");
        num2 = userinput.next();

        String[] input = new String[5];
        input[0] = num1;
        input[1] = " ";
        input[2] = calc;
        input[3] = " ";
        input[4] = num2;


        if(calc.equals("+")){

            int x, y;
            x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
            System.out.println(num1 + " " + calc + " " + num2 + " " + "=" + " " + operation.Add(x,y));
            //System.out.println(num1 + " " + calc + " " + num2 + " " + "=" + " " + (x+y));
        }    
        else if(calc.equals("-")){
            int x, y;
            x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
            System.out.println(num1 + " " + calc + " " + num2 + " " + "=" + " " + operation.Subtract(x, y));
            //System.out.println(num1 + " " + calc + " " + num2 + " " + "=" + " " + (x-y));
        }   
        else if(calc.equals("*")){
            int x, y;
            x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
            System.out.println(num1 + " " + calc + " " + num2 + " " + "=" + " " + operation.Multiply(x, y));
            //System.out.println(num1 + " " + calc + " " + num2 + " " + "=" + " " + (x*y));
        }   
        else if(calc.equals("/")){
            int x, y;
            x = Integer.parseInt(num1);
            y = Integer.parseInt(num2);
            System.out.println(num1 + " " + calc + " " + num2 + " " + "=" + " " + operation.Divide(x, y));
            //System.out.println(num1 + " " + calc + " " + num2 + " " + "=" + " " + (x/y));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The operation is not valid. You can give +, -, *, / for operator!");
            }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}